# Multibind not working in XAML/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I need to calculate the width of an ItemsControl WPF item, however I need to pass not one but two parameters. Here is what it looks like:

```
<ItemsControl.Width>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource animationKeyPositionConverter}">
      <Binding Path="CurrentFrame" ElementName="UC" />
      <Binding Path="CurrentZoom" ElementName="UC" />
   </MultiBinding>
</ItemsControl.Width>
```

The converter looks like:

```
internal class AnimationKeyPositionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var frame = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
        var zoom = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);

        return (double)(frame * zoom);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This converter worked with another multibind (using Setter, another control), however it will not work with ItemsControl.Width. Any reason why? When the multibind is reached, it crashes with:

"'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

'Set property 'System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding.Converter' threw an exception.'"

I cannot find any more info on the exception, the debugger output only states that at line 266 (the first line of the multibind with the converter attribute) threw an exception. It is worth noting again that this exact same multibind converter and syntax worked in another xaml control, but once I put it in ItemsControl.Width it started throwing exceptions and crashing.

I set a breakpoint at the converter and the code isn't even being reached.

Comment: Can you show the element named UC as well in your xaml?

Comment: And, what's the exception that was thrown?

Comment: Are AnimationManager.CurrentFrame and current zoom dependency properties? If not, they wont work.

Comment: @ScottNimrod That's not true. The *source* property of a binding does not need to be a dependency property.

Comment: @Ali, please check which exception is thrown exactly. The error message looks as if the problem was setting the MultiBinding's Converter property. How do you declare the `animationKeyPositionConverter` resource?

Comment: @Clemens What is a "source property"? Do you mean the Source attribute? I was refering to the Paths (CurrentFrame and Zoom). Those paths need to be registered as dependency properties in order for the appropriate binding strategy to be executed (i.e. annimation, local, style, etc.).

Comment: @ScottNimrod A binding has a source and a target property. The source property is specified by the binding's Path. The target property is the one that the binding is applied to (which has to be a DP). In the expression `P1="{Binding Path=P2}"`, P1 is the target property and P2 the source property. You may want to take a look at the *Basic Data Binding Concepts* section in the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Maybe it's worth mentioning that in case of a MultiBinding (as in the question), the Bindings are not applied to any target property, but instead are managed by the MultiBinding. Still, the source properties don't need to be dependency properties.

Comment: @Clemens INotifyPropertyChange relies on dependency properties in order to work.Consider reviewing Dependency Properties Overview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ScottNimrod That's also wrong. INotifyPropertyChange hasn't got anything to do with dependency properties. DependencyObject does not even implement that interface. What they have in common is that you often have view model classes that implement INotifyPropertyChanged (to notify about property changes). The properties of these view model class are then used as source properties in bindings to dependency properties in view classes. Like in `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>`, where `Text` is a DP and `MyText` may raise the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: @ScottNimrod And just to make this more clear, I'll cite the only mention of INotifyPropertyChanged in the *Dependency Properties Overview* article that you've linked: "Dependency properties, or the DependencyObject class, do not natively support INotifyPropertyChanged ...".

Comment: @sthotakura I've looked everywhere and cannot find any more info, the debugger only says that the line of the multibind threw an exception but it does not give more info than that.

Comment: @Clemens I've added the converter declaration to the original post.

Comment: And the resource `animationKeyPositionConverter` is actually an AnimationKeyPositionConverter?

Comment: Yep, I am using converters a few times in my project but they are all single bindings. Only this one is giving me issues even if I am doing it pretty much the same way.

Comment: @AliEgseem I would suggest posting in your question the stack trace of the exception, as caught by the debugger. This would indicate whether the problem is related to the XAML (and thus thrown when the XAML is loaded/parsed) or related to the `AnimationKeyPositionConverter` code (eg. `values[0]` not being an int, or `values[1]` not being a double). I suspect the former though, given the text of the exception message that you've already posted.

Comment: @AliEgseem Is it possible that the element named "UC" that you are using for the bindings might not be accessible via the visual tree from the place where the **ItemsControl** is declared?

Comment: I have added more info on the exception I found, "'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll". I am not sure about the visual tree or even the element UC because I am new to WPF, but it has worked for every other binding I've done except this one for some reason.

Comment: Is there an InnerException, and if yes, what is its message?

Comment: How do I find the InnetException using C#?

Comment: Where is your `animationKeyPositionConverter` defined? Is in the same xaml file as `ItemsControl`? What is `AnimationManager`?

Comment: @user2250152 `animationKeyPositionConverter` is defined in a separate .cs file, one folder up, named TimelineConstants (where most of my functions and converters are). ItemsControl is in the .xaml file one folder down. AnimationManager is what I use to reference properties defined in a separate file, in the same directory as Timeline Constants.

Comment: @AliEgseem To see the InnerException, click on "Show details" at the bottom of the exception popup in VS. Then a dialog window should appear containing a collapsed tree view (just one line "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException"). Expand this line, and one of the child items is the InnerException. In case of a XamlParseException, usually the description of the InnerException (in the right column) tells you what went wrong.

Comment: @Golvellius I do not get a show details option, the popup gives me "break, continue" as options.

Comment: @AliEgseem Hm, strange. You could wrap the line where the relevant InitializeComponent() is called in a try{} block then, and within the associated catch(Exception e) {} block display the message/description of the InnerException in a MessageBox like so: MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.Message);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by changing the binding paths I was using. I'm not sure why CurrentFrame and CurrentZoom threw an error together but using different paths (specifically, specifying a relativesource for CurrentZoom) I was able to get the results I needed. The converter wasn't really the issue, although changing the `(double)` casting to `System.Convert.ToDouble` got rid of the InnerException. I also changed the `ToInt32` conversion to a double as well.