# WPF Multibind converter not returning value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters, multibinding

I have a multibind calling a converter with two bindings. For some reason it does not return anything. I put

```
<ItemsControl.Width>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TimelineWidthConverter}">
        <Binding Path="AnimationManager.MaxFrame" ElementName="UC" />
        <Binding Path="AnimationManager.CurrentZoom" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TimelineAnimationView}}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</ItemsControl.Width>
```

in the XAML file, and the converter reads:

```
internal class MaterialTimelineWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length != 2 || ReferenceEquals(values[0], DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) || ReferenceEquals(values[1], DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
        {
            return 240;
        }

        var maxFrame = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
        var currentZoom = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);

        return currentZoom*maxFrame;

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object values, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that, if I change the XAML file to be:

```
<ItemsControl.Width>
    280
</ItemsControl.Width>
```

It works, but if I simply return 280 in the converter it just doesn't do anything. It's as if it just returns nothing but it gives no errors.

The converter worked before, when it was only a single value converter (traditional binding, no multibinding), but as soon as I added the second property and made it multi it does not work. Any tips?

Comment: Your converter should return a `double` value, not an `int`.

Comment: @EliEgseem I'm agree with @Clemens, the problem is in your converter class while trying to convert `double` to `int`. Please, try cast the values array items to `double`.

Comment: You had already done it right in the converter in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28752481/1136211) :-)

Comment: Yeah, they are two different converters but the idea is the same. For some reason the other one crashes but this one does not. Thanks for the input. I'll pick an answer then I give it a try tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by a multi-value converter must exactly match the type of the target property. Hence it must a return a `double` value, not an `int`.

You will also have to do a correct conversion of the two input values. Your current code assumes that both the `MaxFrame` and the `CurrentZoom` properties of the AnimationManager class are of type `int`. In case they are actually `double`s, change the conversion appropriately.

```
public object Convert(
    object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values == null || values.Length != 2 ||
        ReferenceEquals(values[0], DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) ||
        ReferenceEquals(values[1], DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
    {
        return 240d;
    }

    var maxFrame = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]); // or ToDouble
    var currentZoom = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]); // or ToDouble
    return (double)(currentZoom * maxFrame);
}
```

A probably better implementation might check if the input value are actually ints or doubles (and thus also eliminate the check for `UnsetValue`):

```
public object Convert(
    object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    double result = 240d;

    if (values != null && values.Length == 2 &&
        values[0] is int && values[1] is int)
    {
        var maxFrame = (int)values[0];
        var currentZoom = (int)values[1];
        result = (double)(currentZoom * maxFrame);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Weird, they were doubles at  first and at some point they turned into ints. I figured if it wasn't fussing about invalid casting it wasn't that type of issue. I will look into it and let you know soon.

Comment: Ah, I've tried it and it works. This solves this issue, but the other converter was using doubles so I am confuzzled as to that issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert a `double` to `int`.

```
...
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{

    if (values == null || values.Length != 2 || values.Any(v => DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.Equals(v)))
        return 240d;

    return values.Cast<double>().Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1 * v2);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Clemens' solution was much simpler to me.

Comment: @AliEgseem It's ok, they're very similar, I wrote it using `Linq` ;-)